# Trigger my own function by clicking power button 3 times

Tags: android, react-native

I want to send a SOS message using my own mobile application by clicking the power button N times

Comment: Please provide more information, what have you tried, research, ... this is way too broad. I would guess this will have to be in a background service to be able to stay up during your events. You can't prevent the power event to be consumed by the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  int counter = 0;
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
            // do what you want with the power button
            counter++;
            if (counter==3){
                //Do your thing
                counter=0;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Yea in that case you will definitely need to implement service that will keep running when app is killed. Didn't go that deep he just asked how to detect 3 clicks on power button

Comment: yea.. he have to use service for this.

Answer (score 0):

First Asking for system permission to draw overlay

after that Starting a service and adds a special view to WindowManager

reference: [Detect power button long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064523/detect-power-button-long-press?answertab=active#tab-top)

Hope it helps..