# Android close power off menu programmatically

Tags: java, android

How do I close the Android power menu programmatically? Apps like [alarmy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=droom.sleepIfUCan&hl=en_IN) are doing it.

I couldn't find out from Android docs as to whether an event listener is there that notifies us of the power menu opened.

Physically, if I click on any region on screen other than the power menu or press back button, the menu gets discmised.

I wonder how can I do this programmatically (I know this is possible, probably via some workaround if not directly via api since alarmy can do it).

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code to detect power button press.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
  int keyPressed = event.getKeyCode();
  if(keyPressed==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER){
    Log.d("###","Power button long click");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked: "+keyPressed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;}
  else
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

credits https://stackoverflow.com/a/39197768/9640177

Now to prevent system from showing dialog, you can broadcast to close all system dialogs.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

Complete solution

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
  int keyPressed = event.getKeyCode();
  if(keyPressed==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER){
    Log.d("###","Power button long click");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked: "+keyPressed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //send broadcast to close all dialogs
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
    return true;}
  else
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

If you want to perform a small action just before shutdown, You can do follow this.
 you can listen for following intent using intent filters.

in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVICE_POWER" />
  ....
  ....//other stuff goes here.

<receiver android:name=".ShutdownReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/39213344/9640177

Once you receive this intent you know that the po

Comment: Looks like the solution I was looking for. Upvoted. Gonna give it a try and then mark as answer if it works. Thanks man!!

Comment: Welcome. Please let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

its called custom Dialog box, you can crate from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31279458/8265484) and there is property like

```
 dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

using this property it should be possible which you want.