# Is it possible to override the power off action?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to modify or override the functionality of power off menu button in android (not the button to screen on / off).

I want to fired a process before the device shutdown, run a process and after that shutdown the device

If this it's possible?

Comment: it is not and should not be possible. If it was, you could start an endless process, and prevent the device from shooting down

Comment: Thanks for your comment @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.You don't have to have a rooted device just use a broadcast.
In manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastreceiver.YourClass">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

YourClass:

```
public class YourClass extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
          if(i.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN")){
                     //Fire your code here      
          }
    }};
}
```

If it sounds impossible,Find another way to do the same thing ;)

Comment: @EduardoRotundo I didn't exactly get what you mean.Your English is not so clear.You want to prevent the shutdown now?And by the way you can also update an answer by pressing the arrow up button.

Comment: You can cancel the power menu on a certain device with root.You also can on other devices I suppose it's simple.If you need it I can help you with that too.(But it should be rooted)

Comment: I test this option and works! so now i go to break the shutdown sequence, because now the phone goes off but the debug point it's still alive until phone off

Comment: Umm,I'm not sure what you mean.So you want to cancel shutdown + process + shutdown manually?

Comment: I want trigger a process when the user press the power off option. This process can take about 20 minutes or less and after that turn off the phone

Comment: Ok I get it now.Well that's gonna be so annoying for the user.But anyway.You should ask another question with a better title mentioning this process is too long.Then call me there,I'll help you with that also.Just if you upvote my answer too.That would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry for not used a more explict title @stevemoretz

Comment: @EduardoRotundo check this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064523/detect-power-button-long-press/39205019

Comment: after read the post and do some tests, i see the ShutdownThread process it's not available to override or modify, because the dispatchKeyEvent only works if the activity has focus

Comment: I'm not really into that,But I give you the idea all you need is to find a way to know when the power button is long pressed now I'll take it from here.You have root.So You do a shell input script to click on 0,0 and it will make the menu go away you do whatever you want now.After you're done by another shell command via root turn off the device the only part left to figure is the first part which is available in that link

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: **No**.

This is not possible, without *custom modification* to your firmware or the core of the Android operating system, for a limited number of devices.
[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10118001/6678991)

So on a rooted device, you might be able to do that.
Check [this](http://whitfin.io/remap-the-android-power-button/) link.

Comment: How can i do it with a rooted device? Because i have it, this idea i know only can run in a rooted device

Comment: i don't have the reputation to vote your answer. I go to test it. Thanks for your answer