# how to use broadcast receiver to detect power button down event?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I found this code for button down event but it works only with activity. 
Can somebody suggest something?

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // Do something here...
    event.startTracking(); // Needed to track long presses
    return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent 
    event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // Do something here...
    return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39205019/6207294

Comment: What's your usecase for knowing if the power button is being pressed when your App/Activity is not in active use?

Comment: actually my motive is to determine the power button down down events in background.I read somewhere that in order to detect power button event in background you need to use broadcast receiver, you cannot use it in service.