# How detect long press Power Button in Android 9

Tags: android

Hello I'm trying to detect the long press power button in android P, 
but nevertheless after several attempts I can not get it

I'm following this thread as a reference:
[Detect power button long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064523/detect-power-button-long-press?answertab=active#tab-top)

The code that I implement is the following:

**Activity**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    public final static int REQUEST_CODE = 10101;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn=findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkDrawOverlayPermission()) {
                    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PowerButtonService.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }

public boolean checkDrawOverlayPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            /** if not construct intent to request permission */
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        /** request permission via start activity for result */
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                startService(new Intent(this, PowerButtonService.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Service**

```java
public class PowerButtonService extends Service {

    public PowerButtonService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        LinearLayout mLinear = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()) {

            //home or recent button
            public void onCloseSystemDialogs(String reason) {
                if ("globalactions".equals(reason)) {
                    Log.i("Key", "Long press on power button");
                } else if ("homekey".equals(reason)) {
                    //home key pressed
                } else if ("recentapps".equals(reason)) {
                    // recent apps button clicked
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA
                    || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
                    Log.i("Key", "keycode " + event.getKeyCode());
                }
                return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            }
        };

        mLinear.setFocusable(true);
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_service_layout, mLinear);
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            //LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
            LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
        }

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                100,
                100,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        wm.addView(mView, params);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="powerbuttonpress">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".PowerButtonService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**service_layout**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Run this code on Motorola Moto One with Android 9 and I can detect the button power without problems, however run the same app on a Samsung Galaxy A10 with Android 9 but it does not detect the power button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919865/detecting-a-long-press-with-android

Answer (score 0):

Because in Android P, the function onCloseSystemDialogs doesn't work. Moreover, if the screen is off, this function doesn't work no matter Android P or others.