# Android 9 Remap power button long press

Tags: android, android-intent, android-9.0-pie, android-toast, accessibilityservice

On `Android 9` I'd like to remap long press `power button` for showing a `toast` message instead of Power menu.
Until `Android 8` I could do that using `intent` `android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS` but this is not working anymore on `Android 9`.
Checking in the forum ([Detect power button long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064523/detect-power-button-long-press?noredirect=1&lq=1)) I've found that I should get the same result using Accessibility Service.

Could you please tell me how I should write the `intent` in this case?

Thanks!