# React native power button long press listener when app is running in background

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, react-native

I want to call a SOS function when user long press the power button.
If there is no library to do this, is there any native method to do so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect power button long press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064523/detect-power-button-long-press)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this library to run a code when the home button is pressed

[react-native-home-pressed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-home-pressed)

You can change the keycode creating a fork of the [repository](https://github.com/evanjmg/react-native-home-pressed)

and, check the long press with a timer.

UPDATE:

You can use this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyevent) to get a keycode event of key up and key down event.

Example:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyEvent) => {
        if (keyEvent.keyCode === 'Keycode of the power button'){
            this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                //Your SOS Function here
            }, 1000)
        }
    });

    KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener((keyEvent) => {
        if (keyEvent.keyCode === 'Keycode of the power button'){
            clearTimeout(this.timeout)
        }
    })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    KeyEvent.removeKeyDownListener();
    KeyEvent.removeKeyUpListener();
}
```