# React native app how to find if power button is pressed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React native app- I want to trigger an app when power button is pressed. How do I achieve this functionality ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native power button long press listener when app is running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824310/react-native-power-button-long-press-listener-when-app-is-running-in-background)