# How to disable the power button?

Tags: android

I would like to know if anyone has accurate answer on how to disable power button in android phone?
I did research and all codes are not working. Still failed. and here is my latest code that didn't work because I guess on our current android version. Does anyone know?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        // Do something here...
        event.startTracking(); // Needed to track long presses
       
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Do something here...
            InsertData3(EmpID,"Backpress",Date_log);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: android studio is just an IDE, it doesn't specifically have anything to do with your question except for the fact that you're using it, so i've removed it :)

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064523/detect-power-button-long-press and make sure you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" /> set

Comment: i tried it already and it's not working.

Comment: I don't know if onKeydown and KEYCODE_POWER are not working in android version Pie.